# Lookup IP address of workstation?

Tags: domain-name-system, command-line-interface

I have a list of computer names that I would like to be able to know the IP address of to RDP/VNC from time to time.

I was wondering if there was a way I could look them up? I am using a Mac but the normal

```
ping PCNAME
```

doesn't seem to work. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dig hostname
```

will work on mac to find out IP address, that assumes that your local network dns configuration has the correct results or it exists in global dns

Comment: Additionally, if you want just the IP address without all the other information, `dig hostname +short` will get you that. If you're on the same local LAN as the hosts and they have [Bonjour/ZeroConf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) names set, you can use `dig computer-name.local +short` to get the IPs, even if they don't have DNS entries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to resolve names from the DNS:

```
nslookup PCNAME
hostx PCNAME
host PCNAME
dig PCNAME
```

One of these should work. If it returns no answer it means your administrator did not configure DNS for them. Then it depends of these are Macs or PCs with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try

sudo arp-scan -I eth0 -l | perl -ne '/((\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3})/ and $ip=$1 and $_=`nmblookup -A $ip` and /([[:alnum:]-]+)\s+<00>[^<]+/m and printf "%15s  %s\n",$ip,$1'

Hope that helps